# Read/More Less Not Working - JS, Jquery, Boostrap-4

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am simply trying to create a lightweight experience that will show a paragraph when a "read more" link is clicked, then close when the "read less: link is clicked.

I have a very limited understanding of JS and JQuery. I am currently using Bootstrap4 and calling in JQuery 3.5.1 through https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js. I placed my JS in an external file that I am calling in through my HTML.

The code I am currently using was written for me by another dev for a different Bootstrap site I work on.
The "Read More" "Read Less" toggle is working but I can't figure out how to get it to show the  one "Read More" is clicked.

Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Ldchavez\Desktop\dailey_portfolio\resources\index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,800;1,300&display=swap">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Ldchavez\Desktop\dailey_portfolio\resources\index.js"></script>
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row align-middle">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 background-color1 ">
                    <div class="row mt-5 ml-4">
                        <div class="col-3 px-0">
                            <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="300"
                                src="C:\Users\Ldchavez\Desktop\dailey_portfolio\images\hero.png"
                                alt="s, wearing a tan suit jacket on a blue background">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9 align-self-center">
                            <h1 class="ml-3">Hello.</h1>
                            <h2 class="ml-3">I'm Name</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="col-12 my-4 px-5 text-justify">
                        <p class="mt-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                            ullamco...
                        </p>
                        <span class="read-more" style="display: none;">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                                exercitation ullamco...</p>
                        </span>
                        <a class="expand" data-more="0" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="expandText(this);">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-8 px-5">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-3 px-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 100%">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200" alt="Card image cap">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
                                        bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-3 px-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 100%">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200" alt="Card image cap">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
                                        bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-3 px-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 100%">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200" alt="Card image cap">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
                                        bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-3 px-3">
                            <div class="card" style="width: 100%">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200" alt="Card image cap">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
                                        bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#more { display: none; }
```

JS

```
function expandText(el) { 
    if (el.getAttribute('data-more') == 0) { 
        el.setAttribute('data-more', 1); 
        el.innerHTML = 'Read Less'; 
        el.previousSibling.style.display = 'inline'; 
    } else if (el.getAttribute('data-more') == 1) { 
        el.setAttribute('data-more', 0); 
        el.innerHTML = 'Read More'; 
        el.previousSibling.style.display = 'none'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here's how w3 does it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#more {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Read More Read Less Button</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
<a href='#' onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</a>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that and tried it but didn't want to use <button> I tried replacing that with an <a> tag but it didn't seem to fire.